# Absolute vertical positioning of parbox

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes

I create signature area like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    %some content here
    \begin{center}\parbox[t]{5cm}{\hrule height 1pt\medskip \textbf{John Doe}\\\textit{Director of something}}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which will look like

[image]

I want it to be always at the same vertical position and horinzontally centered - no matter how high the content above it will be.

Do you have any idea how that can be realized?

Comment: Is `\vfill` what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, thank you! Could you please create this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative is use Tikz with current page node. You may change the shift coordinates to the place you want.[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node [anchor=north, shift={(5cm,5cm)}]  at (current page.south west) {%
\parbox[t]{5cm}{\hrule height 1pt\medskip \textbf{John Doe}\\
\textit{Director of something}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to use it at last page (or being sure that a new page will follow) you can use `\vfill` to place signature at page bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\signature}{\vfill\begin{center}%
           \parbox[t]{5cm}{\hrule height 1pt\medskip \textbf{John Doe}\\%
           \textit{Director of something}}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \signature
    \newpage
    \lipsum[2]
    \signature
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \signature
\end{document}
```

[image]